# text not rendering in div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have following CSS:

```html
#navigation {
  background-color: #ededed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0; 
}

#meet {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #088A85;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#meet p {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: 
 }

#meet a, #develop a, #beinformed a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.council {
  background-image: url(council.png);
}
```

And following HTML code:

```html
<div id="navigation">
<div id="meet">
<p>THIS TEXT IS NOT SHOWN</p>

 <span class="button council">
 <a href="djfdf">council</a>
 </span>
 <span class="button tacticalgroup">
 <a href="dfkl">tactical group</a>
 </span>
 
</div>
```

For some reason the text in the Paragraph is not shown. I have tried various things (z-index etc), but it is not working.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You've forgotten to reset the size of the text after setting it to 0

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: thanks, i noticed it too now. was confusing.

Comment: Please check this link:-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I had put font-size to a value of 0 and that explains all why the text in the P is not shown. I have therefore set the font-size of the P element element to a higher value and that solves the problem.